# Any place I can find the percentage of NoSQL vs SQL databases in around (-4, +2 years) 2008? If not, what are your estimates, why?

Tags: sql, database, cassandra, nosql

I failed to find anything on Google. This would be very useful info for the school paper I'm writing on Cassandra. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: https://db-engines.com/en/ranking

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Unfortunately, the graphs only seem to go back as far as 2013 :( but thank you, it's a useful site nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't feel that this question is really a good fit for Stack Overflow, I'll do my best to help (before it gets closed).

In addition to [db-engines.com](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking), I think a good place to get a feel the database usage trends is (in fact) Stack Overflow.  This site has been around since 2008, and therefore has data on some of these trends.

After all, if a database is popular, you'll have people asking how to use it.  If anything, the total number of questions per tag should give you a clue.  For instance, I can go to the [MongoDB tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), and see that 125,646 questions have been asked about it.

You could also try running queries on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/), like this one:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1157441/nosql-datastore-questions-by-year

In this query, someone wanted to see the number of questions asked per year on MongoDB, Cassandra and ScyllaDB.  By looking at the number of questions per year should provide an idea around whether the DB is trending up, down, and by how much.  For this query, it would be easy to add whichever additional databases you wanted to see to the `IN` clause.